# Find the degree of the extension of $\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{2}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I have done the following work:

Let $\alpha = \sqrt{3+2\sqrt{2}}$. Square both sides, so $\alpha^2 = 3+2\sqrt{2}$.

Then $(\alpha^2 - 3)^2 = (2\sqrt{2})^2$. Simplify, we can get $\alpha^4-6\alpha^2+1=0$. This means that $\alpha$ is a root of the monic polynomial $p(x)=x^4-6x^2+1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Then this means $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now, if $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, then the degree of the extension field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{2}})$ is equal to the degree of $p(x)$, which is 4. However, $p(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ since \begin{align*}
p(x)&=x^4-6x^2+1\\
&=(x^4-2x^2+1)-4x^2\\
 &= (x^2-1)^2-4x^2\\
&=(x^2-2x-1)(x^2+2x-1)
\end{align*}
I saw another post saying that this means the degree of the extension field is 2. I don't understand this at all. Could someone help me with this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, the degree is not 1, because $\alpha$ is irrational. It is at most two, because it's a root of either $x^2-2x-1$ or $x^2+2x-1$, so the basis over $\mathbb Q$ will be $(1, \alpha)$, since $(1, \alpha, \alpha^2)$ is linearly dependent (because appropriate polynomial has a root at $\alpha$). Therefore, the degree is exactly two.

Comment: How does $\alpha$ be a root of any of the two quadratic polynomials? I plugged it in both of them, none of them are 0. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @xf16 It must be a root of one of the two, because it is a root of their product. Check your calculations.

Comment: @xf16 $\alpha$ can be rewritten as $1+\sqrt2$ which may make computation easier

Answer (score 3):

Because $$\sqrt{3+2\sqrt2}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt2+2}=\sqrt{(1+\sqrt2)^2}=1+\sqrt2,$$
which says that the degree is equal to $2$.